# Como definir TitleCase usando regex em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, regex, sensibilidade-de-caixa

Eu tenho essa function:

```
 var titleCase = function(s) {
         return s.replace(/(\w)(\w*)/g, function(g0, g1, g2) {
              return g1.toUpperCase() + g2.toLowerCase();
         });
    }
```

Se eu chamar ela passando alguma coisa ela trabalha certo:

```
var teste = titleCase("apenas um teste"), //"Apenas Um Teste"
    teste2 = titleCase("oUTRO.tesTE");     //"Outro.Teste"
```

Mas quando eu tenho um upperChar no meio do texto, ele deve mante-lo, mas ao invez disso está ignorando-o:

```
var teste3 = titleCase('testeControl'); //"Testecontrol"
```

Alguma sugestão para que eu tenha no `teste3` o resultado `"TesteControl"`?

Não importa se quebrar o `teste2`.

Comment: +1 muito legal essa pergunta

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basta substituir `g2.toLowerCase()` por apenas `g2`, de forma que não aconteça a passagem para caracteres minúsculos dos que estiverem no meio da palavra:

```
var titleCase = function(s) {
         return s.replace(/(\w)(\w*)/g, function(g0, g1, g2) {
              return g1.toUpperCase() + g2;
         });
    }
```

Mas como você mesmo já disse, o `teste2` não vai mais ficar com os caracteres do meio minúsculos, ficando assim quebrado.

### [jsfiddle de exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/c2m4v/1/)